# How can I keep the VSCode HTML-language-server formatting from breaking the frontmatter in a WebC-component?

Tags: language-server-protocol, eleventy, yaml-front-matter, helix-editor

I am working on an `11ty` (eleventy) blog in the multimodal editor `helix` using `WebC` as a templating language. To get syntax-highlighting and autoformatting for different languages, `helix` requires a compatible language server to be installed and offers a curated list of compatible LSPs.
For `HTML`, they recommend the [VSCode HTML LSP](https://github.com/hrsh7th/vscode-langservers-extracted).
I am using that for WebC as well, since it is valid markup. I do get syntax highlighting and code-formatting (on save and on demand) now. However, the frontmatter of the `WebC`-component is formatted as well, such that the indentation is removed - breaking the `pagination`-key which has indented sub-keys that lose their indentation.

To illustrate, before formatting:

```
---
layout: "_layouts/document.webc"
title: home
pagination:
  data: collections.post
  size: 2
  alias: posts
  reverse: true
---
```

and after the broken variant:

```
---
layout: "_layouts/document.webc"
title: home
pagination:
data: collections.post
size: 2
alias: posts
reverse: true
---
```

I have looked into the helix-logs when opening my `WebC`-component with `hx -v my-component.webc`and then `:log-open`, and the back-and-forth of helix and the LSP are visible like so:

```
2023-10-17T14:18:04.923 helix_lsp::transport [INFO] -> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/formatting","params":{"options":{"insertSpaces":true,"tabSize":2},"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///<redacted>.webc"}},"id":1}
2023-10-17T14:18:04.966 helix_lsp::transport [INFO] <- {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[{"range":{"start":{"line":0,"character":0},"end":{"line":28,"character":8}},"newText":"---\nlayout: \"_layouts/document.webc\"\ntitle: home\npagination:\ndata: collections.post\nsize: 2\nalias: posts\nreverse: true\n--- <redacted>]}
```

I assume there must be a possibility to configure the LSP such that it will (best case) ignore the frontmatter entirely, or maybe tell helix to ignore it when sending the string TO the LSP.